# Setting starting path on Visual Studio Python Interactive shell

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Writing Python code, I used to execute all code from `*.py` file in Interactive Window (IW) by pressing `Ctrl+Enter`. It's where I test code and write further one.

Now I need to run some code that depends on another `*.py` file, located in another folder.

```
sys.path.append("../tools/")
from email_preprocess import preprocess
```

While it works perfectly when I open it *normal* way (pressing F5 in Visual Studio), it doesn't work when I try to open it in Interactive Window.

> ImportError: No module named email_preprocess

It's probably because Interactive Window work in another place in folder tree, it starts from another path and it simply can't find `../tools/`

Are there any ways to set where (which path) will Python Interactive start in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Good question! I've stumbled upon this as well, added some intermediate answer to somewhat related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187185/python-3-6-in-visual-studio-2017-how-to-run-program-in-the-interactive-shell

Comment: That problem already exists at design time - I've noticed that Intellisense is unable to locate the file... Also the problem occurs even if I try to import files in the same folder.